# Using many iframes of same target page with one-time call (no multi calls of target)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a content page A which also contains 3 iframes of page B.

Page B contains 3 banners, each one inside a separate div with unique ID.
So, page B is like:
    `<div id=1">`banner1`</div>`
    `<div id=2">`banner3`</div>`
    `<div id=3">`banner3`</div>`

and Page A calls:

```
<iframe src="/B.php#1"></iframe><br/>
<iframe src="/B.php#2"></iframe><br/>
<iframe src="/B.php#3"></iframe><br/>
```

The problem is that this way Page B will be called and re-created 3 times, resulting an undesired banners' rotation, since banners are delivered through Google's DFP, following some rules and criteria.

Is there a way that Page B will be first created (once ond only) and then page A to read & "use" the elements, instead of having each iframe call to recreate the entire B page for itself?

thank you in advance

Comment: Is page b a complete page, or just the 3 divs?

Comment: Normal head, body & html parts. Google's DFP .js file is called in HEAD, and few body style attributes.No other contents in page.